# A map between connected $n$-dimensional CW complexes is a homotopy equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, higher-homotopy-groups

> Show that a map between connected $n$-dimensional CW complexes is a homotopy equivalence if it induces an isomorphism on $\pi_i$ for $i\leq n$. [Pass to universal covers an use homology].

I'm in the middle of proving the above statement. As in hint, for the given map $f:X\to Y$ between connected $n$-dimensional CW complexes, let $\tilde{f}:\tilde{X}\to\tilde{Y}$ be a lift of $f$ where $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are universal covers of $X$ and $Y$. Using the fact that $f:\pi_i(X)\to\pi_i(Y)$ is an isomorphism for all $i\leq n$ and $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are simply connected, $\tilde{f}_*:\pi_i(\tilde{X})\to\pi_i(\tilde{Y})$ is an isomorphism for all $i\leq n$. Using relative Hurewicz theorem, one can show $\tilde{f}_*:H_i(\tilde{X})\to H_i(\tilde{Y})$ for $i\leq n$.

Now the problem is that I want to say $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ have $n$-dimensional CW complex structures. But it seems to be a very [nontrivial fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1148918/668308). Is there another way that avoids using this fact?

Answer (score 1):

It is a very nontrivial fact because it appeared in a paper once? I do not agree. This fact is not hard to prove, and can be assigned as an exercise in a first algebraic topology course. So I will point you the right directions and let you give a proof, which hopefully you will write up as an answer.

**Hint.** Use Hatcher Proposition A.2 to define the cell structure. Clearly you want cells upstairs to project to cells downstairs, so you need to understand something about lifting along covering maps: so see the section titled "Lifting properties" in Hatcher 1.3.

Comment: It's not too hard but not that easy. You do have some point set topology details to check